# Apache RewriteRule - How to prevent internal redirect?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, httpd.conf

On Ubuntu 14.04, using Apache 2.4.7, I'm trying to redirect all of the HTTP requests in a subdomain to a single PHP file.

For example, that the request `api.exampleapp.com/auth/login` will be redirected to `/var/www/example-api/api.php?q=auth/login`

All of the code is located at:

```
/var/www/example-api
```

In this directory is a single api.php script that handles everything, and other libraries and resources that should not be publicly available.

This is the configuration in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/api.exampleapp.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@exampleapp.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example-api
  ServerName api.exampleapp.com
  <Directory "/var/www/example-api">
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On
    LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I'm requesting `/var/www/example-api`, I get a 500 response.

This is the output I get in `error_log` (irrelevant data like times was removed):

```
[rid#a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example-api/] add path info postfix: /var/www/example-api/auth -> /var/www/example-api/auth/login
[rid#a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example-api/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/example-api/auth/login -> auth/login
[rid#a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example-api/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'auth/login'
[rid#a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example-api/] rewrite 'auth/login' -> 'api.php?q=auth/login'
[rid#a0/initial] split uri=api.php?q=auth/login -> uri=api.php, args=q=auth/login
[rid#a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example-api/] add per-dir prefix: api.php -> /var/www/example-api/api.php
[rid#a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example-api/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/example-api/ with /
[rid#a0/initial] strip matching prefix: /var/www/example-api/api.php -> api.php
[rid#a0/initial] add subst prefix: api.php -> /api.php
[rid#a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example-api/] internal redirect with /api.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rid#20/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/example-api/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/example-api/api.php -> api.php
[rid#20/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/example-api/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'api.php'
[rid#20/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/example-api/] rewrite 'api.php' -> 'api.php?q=api.php'
[rid#20/initial/redir#1] split uri=api.php?q=api.php -> uri=api.php, args=q=api.php&q=auth/login
[rid#20/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/example-api/] add per-dir prefix: api.php -> /var/www/example-api/api.php
[rid#20/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/example-api/] initial URL equal rewritten URL: /var/www/example-api/api.php [IGNORING REWRITE]
```

How do I prevent the internal redirect after the rewrite?

I tried adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/api.php` and slightly other variations, but nothing worked.

Comment: If you aren't using `htaccess` then better take that tag out from the question.

Comment: ok, although I think `.htaccess` users can benefit from this question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add before `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Not rewrite real file or folder

Answer (score 1):

Substitutions in virtual host context do not generate an internal redirect. Pull you rules out of directory context and make the match and substitution absolute.